# ¿Cómo hago para crear una Function en PL/Sql que retorne un Varchar en Formato XML? si tienen ejemplos

Tags: xml, plsql

Salido tipo:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <env:Header xmlns:urn="urn:miniteriorwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
       <env:Body xmlns:urn="urn:miniteriorwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ns1:DatosSalida xmlns:ns1="urn:wsdl">
             <ns1:apellido>LALALA</ns1:apellido>
             <ns1:nombres>Pepepe Lelele</ns1:nombres>
             <ns1:fechaNacimiento>1948-01-01</ns1:fechaNacimiento>         
          </ns1:DatosSalida>
       </env:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Oracle tiene liberías específicas para devolver ese tipo de resultlados (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx20ppl.htm). No son consultas simples y usualmente implican crear stored procedures.
Un ejemplo: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_format_output_html_xml.htm

Comment: Gracias ahí encontré también para el Select:
XMLELEMENT
XMLAGG
XMLFOREST

Estoy probando y por lo pronto funcionan bastante bien pero me falta más conicimiento

Comment: @G'Kuan siempre he consumido información de este extraordinario sitio web, y por primera vez estoy colaborando, tendrás la posibilidad de darme puntos para aumentar mi reputación? Para acumular el mínimo de 15 que se requiere para poder votar. Gracias desde ya

Comment: Los votos positivos se pueden dar siempre, sin importar la rep. @G'Kuan Puedes ponerlo como respuesta con un ejemplo de uso y te la pueden marcar como aceptada ;)

Answer (score 0):

Una forma fácil seria utilizando el paquete XMLTYPE.createXML.
Seria algo así:

```
declare
v_peticion_xml xmltype;
 v_peticion_txt varchar2(4000);
begin

 v_peticion_txt := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                       <env:Header xmlns:urn="urn:miniteriorwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                       <env:Body xmlns:urn="urn:miniteriorwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                          <ns1:DatosSalida xmlns:ns1="urn:wsdl">
                             <ns1:apellido>LALALA</ns1:apellido>
                             <ns1:nombres>Pepepe Lelele</ns1:nombres>
                             <ns1:fechaNacimiento>1948-01-01</ns1:fechaNacimiento>         
                          </ns1:DatosSalida>
                       </env:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>';
                    
 v_peticion_xml := XMLTYPE.createXML(v_peticion_txt);
 
end;
/
```